# Count the number of entries that has character A, B, C for a given column

Tags: mysql, sql

If a database table has a column whose values are like 'A.B', 'C.D', 'A.C', how can I use sql queries to find out the numbers of entries that has 'A', 'B', 'C' or 'D' (group by characters)?

I was expecting the result to be:

```
 _________________________
|  Characters| COUNT(*)   |
|*************************|
|    A       |    10      |
|*************************|
|    B       |    15      |
|************|************|
|    C       |     8      |
|************|************|
|    D       |     17     |
|____________|____________|
```

An entry for the column that has both 'A' and 'B' (like 'A.B') should be counted in both 'A' and 'B'.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using pattern matching.  Here is one method:

```
select pattern.name, count(t.column)
from (select '%A%' as pattern, 'A' as name union all
      select '%B%' as pattern, 'B' as name union all
      select '%C%' as pattern, 'C' as name union all
      select '%D%' as pattern, 'D' as name
     ) patterns left join
     t
     on t.column like patterns.pattern
group by pattern.name;
```

Note that this uses a subquery to define a "derived table" for the patterns.  This exact syntax may not work in all databases, but something similar should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
create table my_table (
  characters varchar(100)
);

insert into my_table (characters) values ('A.B');
insert into my_table (characters) values ('C.D');
insert into my_table (characters) values ('A.C');

select 'A' as letter, count(*) from my_table where characters like '%A%'
union select 'B', count(*) from my_table where characters like '%B%'
union select 'C', count(*) from my_table where characters like '%C%'
union select 'D', count(*) from my_table where characters like '%D%';
```

Result:

```
letter  count(*)
------  --------
A              2
B              1
C              2
D              1
```